# How to recompile the kernel without the sources?

Tags: kernel, compiling

Is it possible to recompile the current running kernel WITHOUT downloading new sources packages?  I just want to reconfigure my currently running & patched kernel. I no longer have the original source build, including several fetched patches which I had downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot compile a kernel without the source. Compiling is something you do with source. You can't drive without a car either.

You can modify the behavior of an existing kernel with boot parameters, writing to sysfs, etc. It depends what you want to do.